# String digit regex replacement

Tags: bash, shell, regular-expression

I'm struggling a bit with this replacement regex, I could not understand why it is behaving this way. What I want to do is to replace all numeric digits after the last `/`:

```
str="aa/a0b0/42"
echo ${str/%[[:digit:]]*/5}
echo ${str/%[0-9]*/5}
```

Both `echo`'s produce `aa/a5` as output. The expected output would be `aa/a0b0/5`.

I'm well aware that I could use tools such as `sed` and `awk` to solve my problem, and I do know how to do it, but I'm looking for a bash-only solution.

I would like to understand why the `[0-9]*` is expanding to 0b0/42 instead of only numeric digits.

The `%` in my regex is to make [back end replacement](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that's a [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching), not a regular expression.

`[[:digit:]]*` means one digit follow by any string, that's why `0b0/42` matched. It's one digit, `0`, follow by a string, `b0/42`.

Now, in `bash`, with `extglob` enabled, you can use `+(pattern-list)` to match one or more occurrences of a pattern:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ printf '%s\n' "${str/%+([[:digit:]])/5}"
aa/a0b0/5
```

You have that syntax by default in `ksh`, which `bash` copied from.

In `zsh`, while you could use those `ksh` patterns with `setopt kshglob` or use `zsh` own `extendedglob` (`[[:digit:]]##`), you can also perform regex replace with the [regex-replace](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-regexp_002dreplace) [function](http://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Functions/Misc/regexp-replace):

```
$ str="aa/a0b0/42"
$ autoload -U regexp-replace
$ regexp-replace str '[[:digit:]]+$' 5
$ print -rl -- $str
aa/a0b0/5
```

If you ensure that the part after the last `/` always numbers, you can do it POSIXly:

```
printf '%s/%s\n' "${str%/*}" 5
```